# PlanckRadiationLaw not working in 11.3

Tags: functions, version-11.3

`PlanckRadiationLaw` is a function that returns the properties of a wavelength in a specific temperature.

```
PlanckRadiationLaw[Quantity[10000, "Kelvins"], Quantity[500, "Nanometers"]]
```

As shown in help[image]
But in this version, v11.3, if I run the code in help, it displayed error with no reason. Why?

[image]

Comment: It works fine on my MMA version 11.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I have solved this problem after some digging into the problem. Turns out the data depends on the database of Mathematica-which should normally be working fine. But however, the data gets updated sometimes. In China the wolfram server is hard to access, and the connection breaks from time to time.
[image] 
So if the connection breaks down before everything is properly updated, it can cause weird behaviors. The way to solve this is get a steady connection, then update the data manually. After this the function worked fine.
[image]